# How to listen to each event that is being sent to spring state machine

Tags: listener, event-listener, state-machine, spring-statemachine

I have a use case where i want to listen to each event that is being sent to my spring state machine and log them . Currently I can see spring only supports listening to OnTransitionStartEvent, OnTransitionEvent, OnTransitionEndEvent, OnStateExitEvent, OnStateEntryEvent, OnStateChangedEvent, OnStateMachineStart, OnStateMachineStop, and others that extend the base event class, StateMachineEvent.

None of these satisfy my use case where I want to do some processing on every event the state machine receives .

Is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

may be you need class `StateMachineListenerAdapter`,method `eventNotAccepted()`,`stateChanged()`,`stateEntered()`, `stateExited()`...

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.